# What's is the fastest language in terms of run time?

Tags: linux, performance, scripting

I have a script that I wrote in linux shellscript that display's terminal information. It runs in about .1 seconds real time and .03 in user time. This is a great speed, but I have more that I want to add and it slows the program down to .4 or .5 seconds. When it was .1 you didn't have a noticable delay in between hitting enter and it finishing running. At .5 there's a delay.

So my question is what language can I write it in that would run the fasted on a linux based distro. I've been wondering if it would be faster to write it in C or C++ and use the compiled version.

Comment: There is no one "fastest."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a complicated question.

The biggest performance problem with bash is that it is mainly a glue language. Many things you do in bash scripts create entirely new processes (a big performance hit).

C and C++ can be extremely fast, but it takes more time to write and extra effort to optimize the code.

To be honest, I suspect that Perl or Python would be a better choice for you. They are fast enough for most things, and should help you avoid spawning many processes.  I'd write it in python, then profile it if it's not fast enough (which will tell you call frequency and execution time for functions/subroutines).

Comment: Both were good answers but I like this one the most. It's worth it to me to go through the code to make it as fast as possible.

Answer (score 2):

A program compiled to native code, like `c` or `c++`, will lways run faster than a equivalent script run in an interpreter.

Whether `c++` is fastest with your application in your hardware environment would have to be profiled against any other target compiled language to get a definite answer.

Comment: Notice that you could code in [Ocaml](http://caml.inria.fr) and compile with the native compiler `ocamlopt` ... and many other programming languages have compiler implementations translated to native code. BTW, some [JIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation)  implementations can also go really fast.